# Корректно ли указывать запятую после ссылок?

Tags: пунктуация

Данная функциональная возможность в личном кабинете меховых изделий https://ihhfwh.ru, отсутствует.

Comment: В это предложении ещё странно то, что у меховых изделий есть личный кабинет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Помимо того, что запятая в этом месте противоречит грамматике предложения (это ошибка), присоединение к URL какого-либо знака *без пробела* рискованно: на некоторых сайтах этот знак может оказаться в составе URL - тогда ссылка не будет работать.